# Fonts not loading from google api when using fontello

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api, fontello

I've modified my MimeType.config file to include all the fontello font types. I have also included the config.json as some have mentioned. Everytime I load up the browser instead of getting the font icon I'm expecting I get that damn square. I see in the console

GET http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda+Caption:800 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Which is occurring on the same line where I am loading in the Fontello fonts css. Has anyone else had luck with getting these fonts to load?